# How to set default login with windows prompt for all intranet users?

Tags: forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I've created claim based one site in sharepoint. I've configured NTLM and FBA both for that site. (for e.g. 5000 Port)

I've also extended site for FBA (internet) Users only (SQL Membership) with different port.(for e.g. 5001 Port)

I can not remove FBA configuration from main site as i need fba user to manage from windows user.

Now, My question is:

Whenever any intranet user come and access my site like

```
http://site:5000
```

it should ask only windows prompt instead of dropdown for windows and forms authentication.

Can i configure in such manner ? let me know if any other approach should be there.

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing FBA from the authentication providers (which you DO need if Windows users must add FBA users to SharePoint groups/permission levels), you could use the SharePoint Automatic Sign In tool (http://spautomaticsignin.codeplex.com/).

We've integrated it with our Extradium product and our customers love it for their internal users.

Answer (score 0):

Remove forms based authentication from the authentication providers on the web application for `http://site:5000`.  This will cause it to automatically use windows authentication for users on that site.

If you would like to manage the FBA Users from that site, you still can if you're using the FBA Pack. It will check to see if the FBA membership settings are available on a different zone and load the FBA users from there.  You will still need the membership web.config entries on the `http://site:5000` web application for this to work.